# I've installed wordpress locally and it works fine but I can't find my sql database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm on ubuntu, I've had wordpress and mysql installed for a while but I need to edit some tables and I've gone into mysql, used `show databases;` but I can't see the wordpress db.

Surely there is a database else wordpress wouldn't be working, so where is it? Why isn't mysql showing it?

What I've been doing so far is.

CLI > mysql > SHOW DATABASES; > only two databases appear, test and information_schema

I've had problems logging into phpmyadmin too, I've entered the username and password in my wp-config but I can't seem to get in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your issue is that you didn't specify the wordpress user and password on the command line, you connected as a default anonymous user that exists in ubuntu for some reason, but don't have access to the wordpress database.  Note that you won't be able to even *see* the database in that case.

If I were you, I'd try a command like this:

```
mysql -u <user> -p <database>
```

where  is the wordpress user and  it's database from the config.  You will be prompted for the password.